# ASP.net custom forms securty

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I am not sure what it is called what I want, so that is the main reason I post here, I am new to asp.net / mvc and just webdevelopement. However I got a WCF service that got (custom) security. (IAuthorizationPolicy, IPrincipal and UserNamePasswordValidator).

However I am failing to find a good article on ASP.net security. All the guides I find is about sql membership provider, with a automatic genareted databse, but ofc I don't want to create a new user table etc, I want to use my old one (with already hunderds of users in it). But I know I ll need to add a new table to keep track of cookies (so I can compare the GUID to the cookie GUID, or something I dunno I am just reading here and there). But could anyone please provide me a good tutorial for custom forms authentication, ps I must also be able to give access to roles,(I got a (role)table for it as well already). Is it then possible to use authorization with atributes like:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
public ActionResult GetUserStats(int userid)
{
```

PS: I know I ll get shot because this question will be too open etc, I did research, didn t find any up to date(ASP.NET mvc 4, the one with all the openauth stuff and webmatrix security preinstalled) article how to do this all.

EDIT: http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/07/asp-net-mvc-custom-authentication/ seems to be the best article I've found so far, but it uses json, and memory reader/writer lol? And it doesn t save sessions in a DB ? Not certain or it is a good method, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it yet, so this is not a personal endorsement but I just read about SimpleMembership and it sounds like exactly what you need.  See [Jon Galloway's excellent blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and Authorization are completely separate in .NET.

For authentication, you could consider writing [a custom MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx), if none of the standard ones meets your needs.

For authorization, you could consider writing [a custom RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx), if none of the standard ones meets your needs.

A MembershipProvider exposes an API for authentication (e.g. ValidateUser) and for managing users (CreateUser, ChangePassword, ResetPassword, ...).

A RoleProvider exposes an API for authorization (IsInRole, GetRolesForUser) and for managing user's role membership (CreateRole, AddUsersToRole, ...).

If you already have administration in place using your existing db tables, you only need to implement the basic authentication and authorization methods: the others can throw a `NotSupportedException`.